# Cannot find peripheral when scanning devices and service , iPad 3 missing

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm using CBManager in my MAC app to discover my iPad3 device, but its not found.

My piece of code is in my Mac app is based in this post :
[Cannot find peripheral when scanning for specific service CBUUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216248/cannot-find-peripheral-when-scanning-for-specific-service-cbuuid)

and in this two simple codes :

```
   _centralMan = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
 [_centralMan scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

and the delagate

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI 

{
NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID, advertisementData);
//Do something when a peripheral is discovered.
}
```

but it is not found and log my iPad3 device.

Bluetooth is on. Im using Mac mini and iPad3.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac application is looking for a Bluetooth peripheral.  iOS is incapable of acting as a Bluetooth peripheral unless you are running an iOS 6 beta, which is still under NDA.  If you are asking about iOS 6 functionality, you should do so on Apple's developer forums, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: As you sad is not possible to paring and exchange data between , via cb. Is rigth?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest watching [Session 705 of the WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) **Advanced Core Bluetooth**.

There is a short demo of how you can create a server / client relationship using your iOS device as a peripheral.

Also look into **`CBPeripheralManmager`**.