# Core Bluetooth doesn't find peripherals when scanning for specific CBUUID

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-bluetooth

It seems this question was "answered" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216248/cannot-find-peripheral-when-scanning-for-specific-service-cbuuid), but without any code to show what they did differently I'm having to ask a new question.

I have my own code with the same behaviour, where scanning for specific CBUUIDs using Core Bluetooth's CBCentralManager on OS X doesn't discover an iOS device acting as a peripheral with CBPeripheralManager (unless it and its services have previously been discovered). To see if it's something wrong in my code, I downloaded [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Running the sample code on two iOS devices works as intended, however when copying the CBCentralManager code to an OS X app, it fails to find the iOS device.

I've uploaded an Xcode project for the OS X app, it's [hosted on WikiUpload](http://www.wikiupload.com/PTI8G2LZ22V835Y) as that seems to be the least dodgy. There's also [a copy on my hosting](http://kanecheshire.com/downloads/BLETEST.zip), if people prefer.

Here's the AppDelegate.m code in the OS X project also (the CoreBluetooth framework is linked in the project):

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager      *centralManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral          *discoveredPeripheral;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData         *data;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize centralManager = _centralManager, discoveredPeripheral = _discoveredPeripheral, data = _data;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    // Start up the CBCentralManager
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

    // And somewhere to store the incoming data
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


#pragma mark - Central Methods



/** centralManagerDidUpdateState is a required protocol method.
 *  Usually, you'd check for other states to make sure the current device supports LE, is powered on, etc.
 *  In this instance, we're just using it to wait for CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn, which indicates
 *  the Central is ready to be used.
 */
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // In a real app, you'd deal with all the states correctly
        return;
    }

    // The state must be CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn...

    // ... so start scanning
    [self scan];

}


/** Scan for peripherals - specifically for our service's 128bit CBUUID
 */
- (void)scan
{
    // This brings up nothing, unlike on iOS where it finds the device straight away

    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]
                                                options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

//    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
//                                                options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

    NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}


/** This callback comes whenever a peripheral that is advertising the TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID is discovered.
 *  We check the RSSI, to make sure it's close enough that we're interested in it, and if it is,
 *  we start the connection process
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

    //Took out RSSI check

    if (self.discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {

        // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
        self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

        // And connect
        NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);



        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}


/** If the connection fails for whatever reason, we need to deal with it.
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect to %@. (%@)", peripheral, [error localizedDescription]);
    [self cleanup];
}


/** We've connected to the peripheral, now we need to discover the services and characteristics to find the 'transfer' characteristic.
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Peripheral Connected");

    // Stop scanning
    [self.centralManager stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");

    // Clear the data that we may already have
    [self.data setLength:0];

    // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
    peripheral.delegate = self;

    // Search only for services that match our UUID
    [peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]];
}


/** The Transfer Service was discovered
 */
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    // Discover the characteristic we want...

    // Loop through the newly filled peripheral.services array, just in case there's more than one.
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]] forService:service];
    }
}


/** The Transfer characteristic was discovered.
 *  Once this has been found, we want to subscribe to it, which lets the peripheral know we want the data it contains
 */
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Deal with errors (if any)
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        // And check if it's the right one
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {

            // If it is, subscribe to it
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }

    // Once this is complete, we just need to wait for the data to come in.
}


/** This callback lets us know more data has arrived via notification on the characteristic
 */
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Have we got everything we need?
    if ([stringFromData isEqualToString:@"EOM"]) {

        // We have, so show the data,
        //[self.textview setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"Text: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        // Cancel our subscription to the characteristic
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        // and disconnect from the peripehral
        [self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }

    // Otherwise, just add the data on to what we already have
    [self.data appendData:characteristic.value];

    // Log it
    NSLog(@"Received: %@", stringFromData);
}


/** The peripheral letting us know whether our subscribe/unsubscribe happened or not
 */
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing notification state: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    // Exit if it's not the transfer characteristic
    if (![characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
        return;
    }

    // Notification has started
    if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
        NSLog(@"Notification began on %@", characteristic);
    }

    // Notification has stopped
    else {
        // so disconnect from the peripheral
        NSLog(@"Notification stopped on %@.  Disconnecting", characteristic);
        [self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
    }
}


/** Once the disconnection happens, we need to clean up our local copy of the peripheral
 */
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Peripheral Disconnected");
    self.discoveredPeripheral = nil;

    // We're disconnected, so start scanning again
    [self scan];
}


/** Call this when things either go wrong, or you're done with the connection.
 *  This cancels any subscriptions if there are any, or straight disconnects if not.
 *  (didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic will cancel the connection if a subscription is involved)
 */
- (void)cleanup
{
    // Don't do anything if we're not connected
    if (!self.discoveredPeripheral.isConnected) {
        return;
    }

    // See if we are subscribed to a characteristic on the peripheral
    if (self.discoveredPeripheral.services != nil) {
        for (CBService *service in self.discoveredPeripheral.services) {
            if (service.characteristics != nil) {
                for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
                    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
                        if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
                            // It is notifying, so unsubscribe
                            [self.discoveredPeripheral setNotifyValue:NO forCharacteristic:characteristic];

                            // And we're done.
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If we've got this far, we're connected, but we're not subscribed, so we just disconnect
    [self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:self.discoveredPeripheral];
}
```

And in AppDelegate.h there's the UUID definitions:

```
#ifndef LE_Transfer_TransferService_h
#define LE_Transfer_TransferService_h

#define TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID           @"E20A39F4-73F5-4BC4-A12F-17D1AD07A961"
#define TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID    @"08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4"

#endif
```

What's the problem here? According to the above linked question the service has to be part of the advertising packet, but as far as I can see that's exactly what the iOS peripheral is doing with

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
```

Comment: If you scan `[ZzZ scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil ZzZ]` (ZzZ for the rest of the code), and log the `advertisementData` in `central:didDiscoverPeripheral:ZzZ`, what does it show for your peripheral?

Comment: @Larme, just `kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1`, even though the code in the iOS peripheral manager advertises with the `CBAdvertisementDataServicesUUIDsKey`.  Also just to clarify, the iOS app is in the foreground.

Comment: Sometimes, the advertisement data is update chunk by chunk. So, maybe with removing the connection part, wait a little. If not, does LightBlue (or equivalent) show the Adv data with the service?

Comment: I'll check out LightBlue in a sec. But the thing is I don't want to have to search every Bluetooth device around me, I want to search by service CBUUID (recommended by Apple, too). My current app already searches every device, and discovers every device's services and characteristics before deciding which to connect to. Not ideal at all, when there's a method specifically for finding the one you want.

Comment: It's just a test, I don't remember the key, but in `advertisementData` there is a key for advertised services. It may point out that the issue is on your iPhone side.

Comment: Very true. LightBlue on OS X can see the TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID after it's been clicked on, but I assume at that point LightBlue is just looping through and discovering services after it's connected?

Comment: And if you stop advertising it in your iPhone part, does LightBlue sees it again? If no, the issue is on the Mac OS X part.

Comment: I ran your code on my Mac with a LightBlue app configured on my phone with your service and characteristic and it worked.  Can you share the code that you are using as your peripheral?

Comment: The code for the peripheral is just the sample code from Apple which is linked above, I've not changed anything there.

Answer (score 8):

CoreBluetooth can be very frustrating. Here are a couple things to try:

#1: A peripheral that has been connected to stops advertising. If you make a successful connection to the peripheral, you'll need to restart advertising.

#2: iOS caches discovered status and provided services. There's no programmatic way to refresh / clear the cache. Try disabling BT on the iOS device and on the Mac and re-enabling it. Then attempt another connection.

#3: There's a problem with your UUIDs. Try scanning for peripherals with the UUID parameter set to nil. You should then discover *all* peripherals in range.

#4: The BT connection on a Mac can be finicky if the Wifi is on. Try disabling Wifi on your Mac and try again. I've found BTLE completely unusable with Wifi enabled so I've had to use ethernet when doing any BTLE dev on my MacBook.

Comment: CoreBluetooth is a PITA, I agree. I actually already have an app for sale that uses it, so fully aware of how ridiculous it can be at times. #1 is new to me, so I'll look into that (but my current app doesn't stop advertising itself. Perhaps because I have background modes on iOS). #2 I have a post on my blog to clear the cache. #3 the UUIDs are okay once it's previously been discovered. #4 Wifi makes no difference on mine. That said, Handoff is causing an issue for some of my users!

Comment: "A peripheral that has been connected to stops advertising. If you make a successful connection to the peripheral, you'll need to restart advertising."

What do yo mean by this?  Its the peripheral that advertises.  Do you mean one needs to restart scanning?

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman no, I mean what is said. If you create a CoreBluetooth peripheral on OSX, it will stop advertising if a central connects to it.

Comment: ahh, thank you.  I thought you were talking about an external peripheral, not in the case of implementing a peripheral.