# CoreBluetooth central manager not discovering multiple devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I developed a Mac app that discovers and connects to multiple iOS devices using CoreBluetooth. I have been testing is with just my iPhone and it has been discovering it, connecting to it, and exchanging data. However, recently I went to test with other iOS devices, the Mac app cannot discover the other iOS devices. It can only discover my personal iPhone, not others' iPhones.

On the mac side I have

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch central.state {
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        println("Central manager state POWERED ON")
        manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([UUID_SERVICE], options: nil)
    default: return
    }
}
```

and on the iOS side I have

```
 func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!, didAddService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {
    if error != nil {
        println("error: \(error)")
    } else {
        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [service.UUID]])
        println("advertising UUID")
    }
}
```

and in every case `peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!, error: NSError!)` on the iOS side is being called. However, the Mac app is only discovering my iPhone, but not any other iPhones running the app.

How can I discover all iOS devices running the app, not just mine?

Comment: I would start with the LightBlue app - see if it can see all the peripherals and if you configure it to advertise as your service, whether the Mac can see it  - that may help work out which side has the problem.

Comment: The LightBlue app is finding the other device, and the proper service and characteristic; however, the name of the device is "iPhone" whereas the name of my iPhone is the correct name, as well as the correct service and characteristic

Comment: Correct, you won't see the actual device name unless you have a pairing established or a connection in place.  I have found that if you have a Mac and an iOS8 device using the same iCloud account then there is an implicit trust/pairing that changes the behaviour of Core Bluetooth compared to a device without the iCloud account - It took me ages to figure out why a sample program using encryption wouldn't throw the pairing dialog :)

Comment: You should, however still see the advertisement from a non-paired/trusted device although with the generic name, so that hints that there is an issue with your Mac app, but the code you have here looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a question open relating to this: [Core Bluetooth doesn't find peripherals when scanning for specific CBUUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280025/core-bluetooth-doesnt-find-peripherals-when-scanning-for-specific-cbuuid?noredirect=1#comment44928001_28280025)

Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with Core Bluetooth on OS X which means it cannot find a peripheral by specific service CBUUID until that service has already been discovered. The same issue is not apparent with Core Bluetooth in iOS.

The only way I've managed to get around this is to, unfortunately, scan for all devices, and then loop through their services to see if they're a peripheral I'm actually interested in.